# How can I add a column for my predicted results in a Pandas DataFrame then save as a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm using `sklearn` if it matters, but I have:

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(
    n_estimators=10, random_state=0, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
regressor.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

My `y_pred` has `shape`: `(3000,)`

I want to add that column back to `X_test` with a header of `job_performance` and then finally save as a CSV. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What's wrong with `X_test['job_perf'] = y_pred`? You should know how to save a CSV from there.

Comment: Can you add as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then save to csv like this

```
X_test['job_perf'] = y_pred
X_test.to_csv('filename.csv')
```